# Odoo Mobile for iOS app

Tags: ios, odoo-9

I want to build ios app using Odoo Mobile.

A saw this app and so more...

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myodoo/id890388033?mt=8

But in github i found Odoo Mobile framwork only for Android till now

https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework

If so, how so many apps are already in App Store using Odoo Mobile?

Please help if you have any clue.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not really on topic on Stack Overflow. Try checking out their support channels and asking the question there.

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/api_integration.html There is WebAPI, my guess is that's what they use.